# Issues with adding a jar to openshift deployment

Tags: java, openshift

When i deploy my web application on my local tomcat, i place java `mail.jar` in `lib` directory under tomcat. But now i'm deploying on `jboss tomcat on openshift` and i can't place the `mail.jar` in `lib` directory under `jbossews-2.0`. How can i deploy my application with this `mail.jar`? I didn't use maven in my deployment, i deleted the `src` and `pom.xml` under my local repo and place my application war file under `webapps`. That's the mode of deployment that i used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen a bad way of deploying your software to your web server.  The recommended way is to package it as a WAR file; e.g. using Maven's "war" plugin.  That will take care of putting any JAR files listed as dependencies into your WAR file ... in the correct place.

However, if you insist on doing your deployment by hand, then the best way to do it is to put dependent JAR files into the webapp itself ... in the `.../mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib` directory.  If you put JARs into the web container's "shared library" directory you have extra problems to deal with:

1. The directory varies depending on what web container you are using.
2. You have to remember what you deployed to the shared library ... and why.  And the next guy your stuff is going to have problems if you don't document your deployment procedure thoroughly.
3. You can (under some circumstances) run into problems with values and classes "leaking" from one servlet to another, resulting in strange runtime type checking problems.

Comment: That's perfect. It worked. How do i package the application with `Maven's war plugin without deploying my source`. I actually haven't used maven before.

Comment: Rather than explaining, I recommend that you read one of the online Maven textbooks.  For example "Maven By Example": http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/index.html.  Chapter 5 is a "simple webapp" example.